# Synthesis Error IN VIVADO HLS

Tags: c++, c, xilinx, vivado, vivado-hls

I wrote C++ Program to sum two numbers. 
During the Simulation I got correct result but in *synthesis.Solution1/.autopilot/db/Adder.pragma.1.cpp:1*, error. 
Please let me know, why I am getting that error message during Synthesis.

Comment: Please post some code!

Answer (score 0):

Post some code!! 
However, follow the tutorial: you cannot synthesize for a lot of different reasons: it seems that the pragmas (used to define the interfaces of your RTL block) are not defined!! Use this [link](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2016_4/ug871-vivado-high-level-synthesis-tutorial.pdf) page 63, chapter 4: **Interface Synthesis**

Update 16/03/2017 11h55:

Please use this code:

```
void adders(int inA, int inB, int sumAB)
{
#pragma HLS INTERFACE s_axilite port=inA
#pragma HLS INTERFACE s_axilite port=inB
#pragma HLS INTERFACE s_axilite port=sumAB

sumAB = inA + inB; }
```

It will synthesize correctly:

[image]

Comment: #include "Adder.h"
void adders(in1_t inA, in2_t inB, out_t sumAB)
{
#pragma HLS INTERFACE ap_ctrl_none port=return
// Prevent IO protocols on all input ports
#pragma HLS INTERFACE ap_none port=in3
#pragma HLS INTERFACE ap_none port=in2
#pragma HLS INTERFACE ap_none port=in1
sumAB = inA + inB;
}

Comment: you can find an update on the previous answer. **Please accept the answer  if it was helpful**

Comment: No, for me it is not working. Header file #ifndef ADDERS_H_
#define ADDERS_H_
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
// Types and top-level function prototype

//int adders(int in1, int in2, int in3);
#include "ap_int.h"
typedef ap_int<8> in1_t;
typedef ap_int<8> in2_t;
typedef ap_int<8> out_t;
void Adder(in1_t inA, in2_t inB, out_t sumAB);
 
#endif

Comment: Test bench code ; #include <stdio.h>
#include "ap_int.h"
#include "Adder.h"

int main()
{
in1_t inA;
in2_t inB;
out_t sumAB;

inA=15;
inB=15;
sumAB = inA + inB;

Adder(inA, inB, sumAB);
cout << "A = "<< inA;
printf("\n");
cout << "B = " << inB;
printf("\n");
cout << "SUM = "<< sumAB;
printf("\n");
}
Error: The top function "Adder"has no output. Possible causes are 1. Output parameters are passed by value 2. intended outputs (parameters or global variables) are never written

Comment: Accept the edit and add the code in the question in the correct form, please.

Comment: No, it is not working. Showing Error during syntheis: top function "Adder"has no output. Possible causes 1. Output parameters are passed by value 2. intended outputs (parameters or global variables) are never written 
Header file 
#ifndef ADDERS_H_ 
#define ADDERS_H_ 
#include <cmath> 
#include <fstream> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip>
 #include <cstdlib> 
using namespace std; 
int adders(int in1, int in2, int in3); 
#include "ap_int.h" typedef ap_int<8> in1_t; 
typedef ap_int<8> in2_t; 
typedef ap_int<8> out_t; 
void Adder(in1_t inA, in2_t inB, out_t sumAB); 
#endif

Comment: Ok: write a new question with ALL THE FILES used in the project. I will answer with the same file's re- written in the right way